# I need a word for a job title with this kind of description

Tags: word-choice

- What would you call a person whom other people could hire to do anything from cleaning up dog excrement to typing up a resume, while also cleaning and painting a  bathroom, picking up and dropping your children off at various functions, planning a weekend getaway, doing laundry (including ironing), planning, shopping and cooking a weekly dinner menu, answering your business phone and collecting payments. Organizing your garage after purchasing and installing shelving. Locating a special recipe off the internet with these exact ingredients. Getting your vehicle serviced, washed and fueled.  Feeding your pets while your away, when they come by to pick up the mail, mowing the lawn and turning on/off lights to have it appear that someone is home.
- Hopefully not all of this in one day but just so you get an idea of the various things they could be doing.
  Example: My job title when I fill out an application is _______.

Comment: Someone who is expected to do all those tasks would either be servant or a *dogsbody*.

Answer (score 2):

A **personal assistant**, also referred to as **personal aide** (PA) or **personal secretary** (PS), is a job title describing a person who assists a specific person with their daily business or personal tasks.

([x](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_assistant))

Answer (score 0):

If a person was required to carry out all the tasks you have described, they really would be a 'dogsbody'.  It was an endless list of menial tasks.  I am assuming however that you wish to find a more socially acceptable term for a dogsbody in the 21st century.

More acceptable terms are:

- Handyman
- Hired hand
- Attendant

Less acceptable, but appropriate terms nonetheless are:

- Gofer
- Servant

Comment: Find me a handyman (and if *he's* a *she*?) who organizes, shops and cooks the weekly menu and I'll marry him or her :>)

Answer (score -1):

It's less commonly used nowadays but I think what you're describing is a *majordomo*.

> **[majordomo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/majordomo)**
>   *noun*
>   ma·​jor·​do·​mo | \ ˌmā-jər-ˈdō-(ˌ)mō  \
>   *plural* **majordomos**
>
> 1. a head steward of a large household (such as a palace)
> 2. BUTLER, STEWARD
> 3. a person who speaks, makes arrangements, or takes charge for another
>      (broadly): the person who runs an enterprise
>      *"the majordomo of the fair"*

The term has declined in use by about 70% since 1900 according to the [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=majordomo%2Cmajor-domo%2Cmajor+domo%2Cmajordomo%2B%5Bmajor-domo%5D%2B%5Bmajor+domo%5D&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmajordomo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmajor%20-%20domo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmajor%20domo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28majordomo%20%2B%20%5Bmajor%20-%20domo%5D%20%2B%20%5Bmajor%20domo%5D%29%3B%2Cc0) below, perhaps reflecting sociological changes as well as changes in terminology. As is the general trend in English, the hyphenated form has gradually given way to the single word, which has been the preferred way of writing it since the early 1970s.

[The uppermost line represents the total frequency of the three forms *majordomo*, *major-domo* and *major domo*.]

[image: comparative frequency of majordomo, major-domo and [major domo], and total frequency of all three forms]